# SugarORM - 'listall' returns empty list

Tags: android, sugarorm

i've got this class:

```
public class ProfileData extends SugarRecord {
@Expose
public Data data;

public ProfileData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public static class Data {
    public long id;
    @Expose
    public String email;
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @Expose
    public String surname;
    @Expose
    public String address;
    @Expose
    public String city;
    @Expose
    public long pesel;
    @Expose
    public long phone;
    @Expose
    public long userId;
    @Expose
    public long clubId;
    @Expose
    public String fullName;
    @Expose
    public long clientStatusId;
    @Expose
    public String provider;
    @Expose
    public String uid;
    @Expose
    public boolean gender;


    public Data(long id, String email, String name, String surname, String address, String city,
                long pesel, long phone, long userId, long clubId, String fullName,
                long clientStatusId, String provider, String uid, boolean gender) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.pesel = pesel;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.clubId = clubId;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.clientStatusId = clientStatusId;
        this.provider = provider;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

I populate this class with data from JSON (with Gson).
Then i call save() method ('data' object is an instance of ProfileData):

```
data.save();
```

My next step is:

```
List<ProfileData> profileList = ProfileData.listAll(ProfileData.class);
```

**And profileList is empty.**

I put this lines into AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="DATABASE"
        android:value="sugar_example_my.db" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="VERSION"
        android:value="2" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="QUERY_LOG"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
        android:value="com.example.my" />
```

And finally in my App class i put this line:

```
SugarContext.init(this);
```

Any suggetions?

**EDIT:**

**I solved this** by adding public Data() {} into Data class and moving

> extends SugarRecord

from ProfileData to Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trouble is that your list  should be `List<Data>`

Comment: Yup, this. And i also added default constructors to ProfileData and Data. Now it's working perfectly.

Comment: buy the way, is this ORM work faster than deafult cursor operations?